# How to convert a 2d bitmap into points with x-y coordinates in python - and fast

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I am working on a motion detection project using opencv/python.
I have reached the point of creating an image bitmap/array where motion that has been detected is represented by 1's in the array, 0's where there is no motion (by subtracting one picture from a video feed from another after a short lag).
I wish to determine my moving targets (where there may be more than 1) by using Numpy's (or opencv's) kmeans algorithm.
However, these algorithms require an input of an array of x,y coordinates to be used.
What's the fastest and most efficient method to convert a 2d image bitmap array to an array of x y coordinates? (i.e. we're talking image processing here, so slow Python code is undesirable).

Answer (score 3):

Numpy's [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) will do this:

Here's an example from the docs:

```
>>> x = np.eye(3)
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.nonzero(x)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

That is, the output is the indices of the non-zero elements in the array.

Comment: Many thanks - that's what I was looking for! I see also from the example in the docs that I can then transpose this to reach my x, y final requirement. Perrrrfict!